# vb.net how to newline to textbox text field, in the designer Properties window?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

In the designer, I added a new multiline textbox, and want to set (in the designer) the 'Text' field to two or three lines.  How do I insert a newline, like vbcrlf?

I tried setting 'Text' to 1/r/n2/r/n3  but it didn't work.

(I want to do this in the designer, which is faster for making changes than modifying the code.)

Comment: as a comment only, are you aware that `\n` is the 'escape sequence' for a newline, not `/n` ?

Answer (score 0):

(I should have remembered this!)

To add multiple lines, simply pull down arrow at far right of 'Text:____' field, then simply hit  then enter next line.